# How to remove extra space around Image in List View of Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

There is extra space on left and right side of the image.

[image]

Comment: I think the best option is used `android:layoutWidth="wrap_content"` for the width, But if you used some margin or padding with this then you should remove them also.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Only solution is to remove gravity or set it to 0.

Comment: can you post your xml here??

Comment: God only can take care & understand new comers. :D

Comment: Gravity attrribute was AutoGenerated. It's fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for ImageView.

Remove `layout_weight` from ImageView if exist.

Comment: I've figured out the solution, Set android:layout_weight="0". Thanks for your reply

Comment: If you show the required UI, we can tell you best way to do it.

Comment: No. It's fine now